# JasperReport: don't print when detail is blank

Tags: jasper-reports

I need to know if there is a way to generate a blank page (or no pages) when the detail section is blank.

I know there is a "When No Data" property, however I have certain print when conditions in the detail that sometimes I do have data but the detail section is empty.

Comment: Why not set "when print" to that condition you say for all remaining sections?

Comment: Ah wow, I hadn't even thought of that. Now I need to see if I could not print a blank page.